# Finding the slope of the recent three data point from each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as shown below

```
    df=pd.DataFrame({'item':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b'],
                 'date':['2020-03-14','2020-03-21','2020-03-28',
                 '2020-04-04','2020-04-11','2020-08-08','2020-08-15',
                  '2020-08-22','2020-08-29'],
                  'value':[1,2,3,4,6,2,4,8,16]})
```

I want to create new data frame df_slope as follows

```
df_output=pd.DataFrame({'item':['a','b'],
              'slope':[1.5,6.0]})
```

here slope is calculated as `round(np.polyfit([1,2,3],[y1,y2,y3], 1)[0],2)` where y1,y2,y3 is the latest three data points.
How do I create this data frame? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

How do I handle insufficient data here? i.e if we don't have 3 data points, say just 2 data points I still want to compute the slope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If necessary first sorting data per groups by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with custom lambda function and select last 3 values of column `value`:

```
f = lambda x: round(np.polyfit([1,2,3],x.tail(3), 1)[0],2)
df = df.sort_values(['item','date']).groupby('item')['value'].agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
  item  value
0    a    1.5
1    b    6.0
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: round(np.polyfit([1,2,3],x.iloc[-3:], 1)[0],2)
df = df.sort_values(['item','date']).groupby('item')['value'].agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
  item  value
0    a    1.5
1    b    6.0
```

EDIT: If need working also for groups with length `2` and `1` use:

```
def f(x):
    lens = len(x)
    a = np.arange(1, min(lens, 3) + 1)
    return round(np.polyfit(a,x.tail(3), 1)[0],2)
        
 
df = df.sort_values(['item','date']).groupby('item')['value'].agg(f).reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael. Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to handle insufficient data here? Make it work even when we have just two (or one) data point.

Comment: @Naseef - sure, give em a sec. Then is passed `[1,2]` instead `[1,2,3]`, right? Is possible one point? Then whats happen?

Comment: @Naseef - then is returned same value? Or `0` ? Or `NaN` ?

Comment: To be honest , I'm not sure how they calculate the slope and intercept. but you can pass a single point to polyfit function.

Comment: @Naseef - Tere is warning for such data, but working, answer was edited.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is sorted correctly you can also use:

```
list_item = []
list_slope = []
for item in df["item"].unique():
    y1,y2,y3 = df.groupby("item").get_group(item)["value"][-3:]
    list_item.append(item)
    list_slope.append(round(np.polyfit([1,2,3],[y1,y2,y3], 1)[0],2))

df_output = pd.DataFrame({"item": list_item, "slope": list_slope})
```